# Subscribe for external Google Calendar via Android programatically

Tags: android, android-intent, calendar, google-calendar-api

I want to subscribe external Google Calendar into my Google calendar via intent from third-party application.
I'm trying to make somehow intent with calendar URL to Google Calendar native application from my application.
I can't find in Google calendar application such functionality, of course if i open the Browser with the calendar url it will be handled from Google web calendar app and it can be imported successfully, but i'm trying to do that with the native Google calendar app.

The idea is simple:

My app -> send Intent(calendar url) -> Google Calendar app

Does anyone do such a thing?